# How do I reference the theme folder in blogengine.net?

Tags: asp.net, blogengine.net

I have a theme in blog engine.net I want to reference a .aspx file in an IFRAME in my theme master page (inside site.master). Something like this:

```
<iframe src='/blog/themes/MCO/ContactForm.aspx' frameborder='0' width='250' height='75'></iframe>
```

Unfortunately this absolute path doesn't work. Is there some sort of helper function to get this reference? Like:

```
src='<%=BlogSettings.Instance.ThemeFolder+"ContactForm.aspx" %>'
```

Comment: Note: I think it might be buried someplace in BlogSettings.Instance Any documentation on this property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one:

```
<img src="themes/<%=BlogSettings.Instance.Theme%>/images/logo.png" />
```

Answer (score 1):

****iframe src='/blog/themes/MCO/ContactForm.aspx'****

Why not try the full path url?

Comment: I know I can do that, but I'm worried if somebody changes the theme name it will break the theme.

Answer (score 1):

The above marked good answer actually works only on the blog home page.
This one should improve:

```
<img src="<%=Utils.ApplicationRelativeWebRoot %>themes/<%=BlogSettings.Instance.Theme%>/images/logo.png" />
```